# AEM Project archetype error for multi-language project

Tags: maven, aem, multilingual, aem-6, aem-project-archetype

I was trying to build an [AEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Experience_Cloud#Products) project with a Maven archetype project version 27 and AEM version 6.4.8.4. I'm wondering to generate the project in two languages, English and [Ukrainian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ukrainian#Proper_noun), but after the generation of the archetype the project is not generated correctly. I had executed the following command for two languages:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate \
-D archetypeGroupId=com.adobe.aem \
-D archetypeArtifactId=aem-project-archetype \
-D archetypeVersion=27 \
-D appTitle="My Multilanguage project" \
-D appId="my-project" \
-D artifactId="my-project" \
-D groupId="com.my.project" \
-D frontendModule="react" \
-D aemVersion="6.4.8.4" \
-D language=en,uk \
-D includeExamples=y \
-D includeErrorHandler=y
```

How can I generate the project in two languages?

Comment: Can you specify what exactly is not "correct"?

Comment: Oh, I think I know what do you mean, it creates an `en,uk` node.

Comment: Right, with this command creates a en,uk node, not two nodes

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the [code of AEM archetye](https://github.com/adobe/aem-project-archetype/blob/6c3d1991e353b3f91f4b0a5de253b92f654bddc1/src/main/resources/META-INF/archetype-post-generate.groovy#L207), I don't think a multiple language rollout is possible. There is no loop over languages and no split of the parameter itself by any specific delimiter, so I think you need to alter that setup later on.